# Cross merge two vectors

Tags: r, vector

How to crossly merge two vectors in R?

For example, from `c(1,2,3,4)` and `c(5,6,7,8)` to construct `c(1,5,2,6,3,7,4,8)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
b <- c(5, 6, 7, 8)

ab <- as.vector(matrix(c(a, b), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE))
ab
[1] 1 5 2 6 3 7 4 8
```

Answer (score 3):

Similar to ycw's method, you could use `rbind` to construct the matrix and then form a vector with `c`:

```
c(rbind(a, b))
[1] 1 5 2 6 3 7 4 8
```

**data**

```
a <- 1:4
b <- 5:8
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option that works also well when the `length` of the `vector`s are not the same would be to `order` by the concatenated sequence of both `vector`s

```
c(a,b)[order(c(seq_along(a), seq_along(b)))]
#[1] 1 5 2 6 3 7 4 8
```

#### data

```
a <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
b <- c(5, 6, 7, 8)
```