# How to "stitch" two vectors together in R?

Tags: r, vector

If I have two vectors

`v1 = c(1, 2, 3) 
 v2 = c(4, 5, 6)`

and I'd like to combine them into

`v3 
 [1] 1 4 2 5 3 6`

Is there a simple function to do this, or should I do it manually?

Comment: Do you need this specific alignment?

Comment: `c(rbind(v1, v2))`

Comment: c(v1,v2) for vectors to concatenate then together regardless of order

Comment: Also duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/45655966/1100107

Comment: Thanks @RonakShah for answer and duplicate, didn't know what keywords to search for